# Receiving an instance of a struct from go lists

Tags: go

I have a struct in go which is:

```
type AcceptMsg struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Rnd  *Round `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=rnd,proto3" json:"rnd,omitempty"`
    Slot *Slot  `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=slot,proto3" json:"slot,omitempty"`
    Val  *Value `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=val,proto3" json:"val,omitempty"`
}
```

I have added instances from that struct into a `acceptMsgQueue     *list.List` 
my question is, how can I access the variables of the instance when I receive them from the list:

```
for f := p.acceptMsgQueue.Front(); f != nil; f = f.Next() {
    acceptMsg := f.Value
}
```

when I put the dot in from of `acceptMsg` in vscode it doesn't recognize it as the correct type and I do not have access to `Rnd` and `Slot` and `Val` as the properties of `acceptMsg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/container/list#Element) a list's element value is store using `any` (a.k.a. `interface{}`):

```
type Element struct {   
    Value any
}
```

so to see your original concrete-typed value, you need to perform a [type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15):

```
acceptMsg, ok := f.Value.(AcceptMsg) // ok==true if dynamic type is correct
```